# Excel VBA, Code name appearing with sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

Why is that when I have the following VBA code:

```
public sub Run
End Sub
```

Sometimes it appears as Run in the macro list on the view tab but sometimes it appears as sheet1!Run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put the macro into one of the worksheet code sheets. This probably occurred by opening the VBE with a right-click to the worksheet name tab and choosing *View Code*.

The macro *can* reside there but it will remain Private to that worksheet unless specifically declared otherwise. Generally, a module sheet is the preferred location.

It's also a bad idea to name your macros with *reserved words*. `Run` is a function as in `Application.Run` and your macro can only cause confusion if it carries the same name.